# Why does printing the owner of a closure in a string cause infinite recursion?

Tags: groovy, closures, stack-overflow

I'm playing with closures and seeing this odd behavior that I can't quite explain:

```
groovy:000> ({ println owner })()
groovysh_evaluate@200b6145
===> null
groovy:000> ({ println "${owner}" })()
groovysh_evaluate@2bf75a70
===> null
groovy:000> ({ ({ println owner })() })()
groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@10f67a01
===> null
groovy:000> ({ ({ println "${owner}" })() })()
ERROR java.lang.StackOverflowError:
null
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall (groovysh_evaluate)
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1.doCall (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall (groovysh_evaluate)
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1.doCall (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        <stacktrace repeats>
```

I figure it has something to do with the fact that the `${}` is itself a closure, but I can't quite pin down why this happens.  The issue does appear related to accessing `owner` as I've not seen it happen with other variables/expressions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases when a closure is embedded inside a GString, `toString()` is not called on the closure unlike variables embedded in GString. In the above case where you see an error, `owner` is the surrounding closure and `toString()` would not be called on the closure.

To get around with it, `toString()` has to be called explicitly on `owner` like:

`({ ({ println "${owner.toString()}" })() })()`

The same is applicable for as many nested level of closures we build.

```
({ ({ ({ println "${owner.toString()}" })() })() })()
```

With proper indentation it would look like:

```
({ 
    ({ 
        ({ 
            println "${owner.toString()}" 
        })() 
    })() 
})()
```

The behavior can be explained with a trivial example.

```
def clos = {return {"hello"}}
println "${clos()}" //prints nothing
println "${clos()()}" //prints hello
```

**Explanation for error:-**
Now coming to the error that is faced, as mentioned earlier, when a closure is embedded inside GString, `toString()` is not called on the closure. Instead the closure is called and then `toString()` is invoked/applied on the result of the called closure. Which means:

`"$owner"` is equivalent to `owner().toString()`.

In the above case, while calling the outer closure it eventually calls itself through the GString implementation [`"$owner"`] and the call grows as a recursion, hence a stackoverflow error.

*Note:*
You can omit `{}` when the variable on which you are applying GString is simple. `"${myVariable}"` is same as `"$myVariable"`. You can do that as long as you are accessing simple properties of the variable. `"$myVariable.class.name"` is good (as long as myVariable is not a map). But when method calls are involved curly braces are needed `"${myVariable.toString()}"`

Comment: Forgot to mention, you would see the same behavior if `delegate` is used instead of `owner`.